# Compare Date with Timestamp in oracle 11g stored procedure

Tags: c#, oracle, datetime, timestamp

I'm very confused from this problem. We use Oracle DB with stored procedures, these are called from C#.

This is problematic part of stored procedure:

```
  IF pi_from_date IS NOT NULL THEN
       where_part := where_part || 'and created_on >= ''' ||  pi_from_date || '''';
   END IF;
   IF pi_to_date IS NOT NULL THEN
       where_part := where_part || 'and created_on <= ''' ||  pi_to_date || '''';
   END IF;
```

pi_from_date and pi_to_date are IN parameters type of DATE. credated_on is column type of TIMESTAMP. I call this procedure from C# code and use C# type DateTime for pi_to_date and pi_from_date.
It isn't working. I don't get any results, but in DB are some records. I tried functions like TO_DATE, TO_CHAR, but nothing is working. Sometimes I get error:

> SQL Error: ORA-00904: "APR": invalid identifier

Could you help me how to solve this problem, please?
Thanks.

**EDIT:**
Here is C# code:

```
var parameters = new OracleDynamicParameters();
parameters.Add("pi_from_date", filterData.From); //DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
parameters.Add("pi_to_date", filterData.To); //DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);

var payments = conn.Query<Payment>("TEST_PCG.find_proc", parameters, commandType: commandType.StoredProcedure);
```

In DB are records with date 1.8.2013.

Stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE find_proc ( pi_from_date           IN DATE,
                          pi_to_date             IN DATE,
                          items_ret              OUT sys_refcursor)
AS 
  stmt varchar2(32767);
  where_part varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
  -- select statement part
   stmt := 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, rownum r__ FROM (SELECT * FROM Payment WHERE 1=1 ';        

   -- where statement part
   IF pi_from_date IS NOT NULL THEN
       where_part := where_part || 'and created_on >= ''' ||  pi_from_date || '''';
   END IF;
   IF pi_to_date IS NOT NULL THEN
       where_part := where_part || 'and created_on <= ''' ||  pi_to_date || '''';
   END IF;
   stmt := stmt || where_part;

   -- get ref cursor from query
   OPEN items_ret FOR stmt;
END find_proc;
```

Comment: You should be using properly typed, parameratized variables instead of  passing dates as strings, or dynamically creating the SQL statement by building strings. Please show the C# portion of your code.  Please also show the rest of the sproc - at least so we can see how the entire statement is built and executed.

Comment: Please show your C# call setup to this procedure, and the procedure declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Your Dynamic SQL considers your date value as a string, and depending on your machine, C# would convert the date into different formats of string (e.g. dd/mm/yyyy, DD-MM-YYYY..etc) so you need to specify that as well. If you have to use D-SQL then your where clause should convert the date value you are passing to a date using `TO_DATE` and have the same date format that you are converting to in C#